# Load Properties file in java

Tags: java, properties

I am not able to load property file using below snippet

```
    URL configURL = null;
    URLConnection configURLConn = null;
    InputStream configInputStream = null;
    currConfigProperties = new Properties();
    try {
        String configPropertiesFile = getParameter("propertiesFile");
        if (configPropertiesFile == null) {
            configPropertiesFile = "com/abc/applet/Configuration.properties";
        }
        System.out.println("configPropertiesFile :"+configPropertiesFile);
        configURL = new URL(getCodeBase(), configPropertiesFile);
        configURLConn = configURL.openConnection();
        configInputStream = configURLConn.getInputStream();
        currConfigProperties.load(configInputStream);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println(
            "Creating configURL: " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(
            "IOException opening configURLConn: "
                + e);
    }
```

Getting  java.io.FileNotFoundException exception.

Comment: I guess this will work => configPropertiesFile = "src/com/abc/applet/Configuration.properties"

Comment: Presumably this is an applet loading from a remote server? Or are you trying to read from the classpath? Either way, try the `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` method.

Comment: @bmorris591 - classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your properties file in java class in this way:-

```
InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(configPropertiesFile);
currConfigProperties.load(fileStream);
```

Also, change your property file path to `src/com/abc/applet/Configuration.properties`

Also you can use this to load it from the classpath:-

```
currConfigProperties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(configPropertiesFile));
```

Answer (score 3):

In case when your properties file in the same place with your class:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
    properties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("properties.properties"));
} catch (IOException e) { /*File Not Found or something like this*/}
```

I case when your properties is in the root folder of your class files:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
    properties.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("properties.properties"));
} catch (IOException e) { /*File Not Found or something like this*/}
```

Also you can pass the pass to your properties file with `-DmyPropertiesFile=./../../properties.properties` and then get it `System.getProperty("myPropertiesFile")`.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP's comment loading is from the class path. So the ClassLoader needs to be used,

```
public void load() {
    getClass().getResourceAsStream("my/resource");
}

public static void loadStatic() {
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my/resource");
}
```

The first method needs to be in an instance context, the second will work from a static context.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well.

```
public static void loadPropertiesToMemory() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    String filePathPropFile = "configuration.properties";
    try {
        input = App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePathPropFile);
        prop.load(input);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

`App` is the class where you have the above method implemented.